# peewee raw query does not work with WITH statement

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, peewee

I have query which works in SQLite Spy (a tool for viewing SQLite Databases) but I can't get the query to work in python with peewee as a raw query.

The (simplified) query is

```
WITH tags(name) AS ( VALUES('foo'),('bar') ) SELECT * FROM tags
```

The (simplified) python code is:

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase(":memory:")
db.execute_sql("WITH tags(name) AS ( VALUES('foo'),('bar') ) SELECT * FROM tags")
```

I get an error

```
peewee.OperationalError: near "WITH": syntax error
```

I also tried the RawQuery function or using SqliteExtDatabase from the PlayHouse extension.

Is this error caused by me or is it a problem of peewee?

Comment: Which Python version?

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CTE was introduced in SQLite as of version 3.8.3

http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_3.html

it is very likely that your Python is using a previous version that does not support WITH
Check sqlite3.sqlite_version_info

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: This is something I hadn't thought about.
my `sqlite3.sqlite_version_info` is `(3, 6, 21)`

I now installed the newest APSW packaged and use it in peewee by the playhouse extension:

`from playhouse import apsw_ext
db = apsw_ext.APSWDatabase(":memory:")
db.execute_sql("WITH tags(name) AS ( VALUES('foo'),('bar') ) SELECT * FROM tags")`

Thank you for your help. It now works.